# MongoDB sort documents using another collection array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'll try to explain the best I can what I want to achieve.

*(note: _id are autogenerated)*

Let's start with the schema I want to query

```
cocktail: Schema = 
    name: { type: String },
    ingredients: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'ingredient', required: true }]
```

Just to state the obvious, name is the name of the cocktail and ingredients are the  elements of composing the cocktail.

To keep it simple, this is the Ingredient schema

```
ingredient: Schema = 
    name: { type: String }
```

Simple and clean.

Let's say I have a users collection in which a user can choose what ingredients it prefer. The ingredients for the users can be empty.

```
user: Schema = 
    name: { type: String },
    preferredIngredients: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'ingredient' }]
```

Now the question: is it possible to query the cocktail collection by the user's favorite ingredients?

I tried with (**me** is a previous query to find the user)

```
db.cocktails.find({ ingredients: { $in: [me.preferredIngredients] }})
```

But it never returns data. My experience is not so great with either mongo or mongooose to dig further

Please help!

Comment: Assuming everything else is ok - { $in: [me.preferredIngredients] } - try to drop square brackets. me.preferredIngredients is already an array and you are creating an array of arrays this way.

Comment: @Anton thanks. I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, you should use [$lookup mongo version 3.6+](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) syntax:

```
db.users.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup: {
       from: "cocktails",
       let: { ingredients: "$preferredIngredients" },
       pipeline: [ 
            { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $setIsSubset : ["$ingredients", "$$ingredients"]},
                 }
              }
       ],
       as: 'matched_cocktails'
     }
   }
])
```

Comment: Well this gives me all users and all the cocktails that match their preferred ingredients. I'll take your code as example to make my code work. Thanks, you're amazing.

Comment: No problem, obviously you can easily add a match phase before the lookup to only filter the relevant users .